# Angular CLI not compatible with Angular version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm upgrading my application from Angular v13 to v14 and I'm running into an error while running `ng serve`.

```
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
but Angular version 14.3.0 was found instead.
```

When searching online, I've found several people with the same issue as me.
One solved it by updating their custom-webpack package, but I'm not using that.
The other is about the wrong `@angular/cli` version being installed. But that one is correct for me as well. Sort of.

Globally I've installed `@angular/cli@14.2.12`, and in the project's package.json I have version `~14.2.12`.
It's slightly behind the angular version I'm upgrading to: `14.3.0` but there does not seem to be a `14.3.0` version of the `@angular/cli`.

I tried downgrading the update of Angular to version `14.2.12` instead of `14.3.0`, but the issue persists. I also tried updating further to version `15.x.x` where both the angular and the angular/cli version are the same, but still it shows the error about version `13.0.0`.

Clearing npm cache or cloning the repo all over again didn't solve my problem either. I'm looking for other suggestions.

This is the complete list of dependencies I have in my `package.json`.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1502.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@maxxton/build-tools": "^344.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.45",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.4",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.3.0",
    "@maxxton/core": "^8863.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^19.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.32.1",
    "d3": "^7.1.1",
    "expr-eval": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "9.16.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.4",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keycloak-angular": "^11.0.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^16.1.0",
    "leaflet": "1.6",
    "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.47.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^13.0.1",
    "npm": "^9.8.1",
    "rison": "^0.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tinymce": "^6.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

Comment: can you check `npm ls @angular/cli` ?

Comment: I didn't know about that command yet. It complained about `@angular-eslint/schematics` so I updated that to `v14.4.0` (before: `^13.5.0`). It didn't solve my error though. This is the output of the command.
```@maxxton/reservation-manager@1.0.0 /Users/paulvandendool/Projects/reservation-manager-client
├─┬ @angular-eslint/schematics@14.4.0
│ └── @angular/cli@14.2.12 deduped
├── @angular/cli@14.2.12
└─┬ @project/build-tools@344.0.0
  └── @angular/cli@14.2.12 deduped```

Comment: Do you have a global CLI installed ?

Comment: Yes. I've got v14.2.12 installed globally

Comment: what does `ng version` outputs ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 14.2.12
Node: 20.3.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.6.7 
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 14.3.0

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.12
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    14.2.12
@schematics/angular             14.2.12
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.9.5

Comment: The error message makes absolutely no sense in that case. Do you mind sharing a repro repo ?

Comment: It's close to midnight where I'm at, so I'll try to recreate it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by upgrading ngx-build-plus to version 14

Comment: I ran into a few other issues and decided to start over with the upgrade. Couldn't solve this issue by running `npm ls @angular/cli`. But your answer did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There were some dependencies requiring an older version of `@angular/cli`. In my case it was my `@maxxton/build-tools` depedency.

I ran `npm ls @angular/cli` in my repository to discover all the dependencies that use `@angular/cli`. The `@maxxton/build-tools` dependency in this case showed it still used v13.